# How to set ViewResolver in Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I've my Spring Boot Web Flux application for quite some time. At this point I wanted to add some exception handlers to my router function:

```
@Bean
RouterFunction<?> router(final GeneratorHandler generatorHandler) {
    return resources("/**", new ClassPathResource("/static/"))
            .andOther(route(GET("/generate"), generatorHandler::renderData)
                    .andRoute(GET("/index"), generatorHandler::renderIndex));
}
```

So I added another bean like this:

```
@Bean
HttpHandler httpHandler(final GeneratorHandler generatorHandler) throws Exception {
    return WebHttpHandlerBuilder.webHandler(toHttpHandler(router(generatorHandler)))
            .prependExceptionHandler((serverWebExchange, exception) -> {
                //process here
                return null;
            })
            .build();
}
```

After this I am having troubles with my view resolver. It can't find any of my views. After investigating I've realized that debugger does not stop in ThymeleafReactiveViewResolver class.

Is that possible that this change changed default view resolver too? How Can I bring it back?

Comment: If you comment out the new `httpHandler` bean, does everything go back to normal?

Comment: @dillius yes it does.

Comment: This section of the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M4/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html#web-reactive-getting-started-manual) makes it seem like you need to provide context information to the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing your `httpHandler` disables quite a lot of support from Spring Boot.

You can declare your own `WebExceptionHandler`, as a component (even an ordered one) and Spring WebFlux will pick it up for you. Without a more concrete example (or at least the stacktrace/error you're seeing), it's hard to understand what's going on.

Spring Boot now supports error handling in WebFlux applications (see [#8625](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8625)), in case it does what you're trying to achieve.